# Missing Export Books Data on Edge Browser on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I use Edge browser to open some EPUB books and it works fine. Except it seems to have the button called "Export Books Data" missing. It is supposed to be under Settings-->General-->Click on Import or Export button--->at the end of the panel.

This is used to export all the edits/notes on the EPUB books. I noticed that this is available on the same version of Edge on another machine (Windows 10 Professional). My windows is Windows 10 Enterprise.

Is this because of the Windows 10 Edition? is it possible to somehow enable it?

EDIT: Add screenshot below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that if you have Windows 10 installed, if you change the country of origin under the region settings from United States to some other country, then the Export Books Data button along some of other settings regarding Books will disappear.

Comment: Yes, I made a test and got the similar result. Looks like some options are only available for specific regions. Thanks for sharing this information. It can be helpful to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

I am available with both edition of Win 10 OS.

I can see that MS Edge settings displayed little different in both edition.

For Win 10 Enterprise edition, Can you please try to check at location below.

> Settings and more -> Settings -> View Advanced Setting -> Export Book Data

[image]

Let me know, If you still not able to find this option in MS Edge. I will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: thanks for your reply. No, it looks very different. For example the first radio button that says "Let sites save....", is under Settings-->Privacy & security panel. The second radio button is way down the same panel away from the first one. And there is no "Export book data" anywhere. I have also checked Settings-->Advanced as well but no luck.

Comment: Can you please inform me, Which version of MS Edge and which Win 10 build you are using currently? If possible than try to post a snapshot of settings in Edge may help us to get better idea.

Comment: Sure...Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.17763 build 17763) + Microsoft Edge (44.17763.1.0) ....thanks.

Comment: I added the screenshot to my question above.

Comment: Looks like you are using Windows insider (17763). Insider version get released before a stable release of update for any OS. It can be the possible reason that MS Edge does not have that button. I suggest you to check for that button with any stable release of Win 10. I have check that Win 10 Enterprise MS Edge 44.17763.1.0 has this option. It is advisable to use latest updates for your Windows.

Comment: I don't believe I am. I went to Home--->Windows insider program, and it says "Join the insider program to get preview builds of ...". If I click on it, then it says that you need to register for an account.

Comment: You can check this image which shows update history. https://i.postimg.cc/q7HgqYL2/13.png

Comment: Thank you so much for following it up. Just final question...if that is the case then, can I get out of this with changing settings? or do I need to reinstall a different edition? What is the latest standard version?

Comment: It is better, if you install the stable version of the Win 10 OS. Insider versions are for tests and getting the feedback about bugs. So that it can be corrected in final release.

Comment: Sorry to reply again. I think I figoured out why it disappears. I installed a new version on a vmware, and registered. But I noticed that when I change the country from US, then the settings disappear. I post this as an answer. If you believe there is a way around that, please give another solution. Thank you.